# An inequality with exponents, factorials and nth roots!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, factorial

**Problem:** Prove for natural numbers $n > 2$, $$(\sqrt{2!}-1)((3!)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\sqrt{2!})\cdots(((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}) < \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}.$$

I am unable to do this one. Please help.

**My attempts**:  By AM-GM we get,

$(\sqrt{2!}-1)((3!)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\sqrt{2!})\cdots(((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}) < \left( \frac{((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}{n}\right)^{n} $.

So, now its enough to show, $$\left( \frac{((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}{n}\right)^{n} < \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}$$ But I don't know how to do that.

I also tried with induction, but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last inequality can be written as
$$(n+1)\cdot\left((n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1\right)<n\cdot n!^\frac{1}{n}$$
or:
$$(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}} -n\cdot n!^\frac{1}{n}< n+1$$
that is straightforward to prove through Stirling's approximation: $n!\approx\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$ gives that the LHS behaves like $\frac{2}{e}\cdot(n+1)$ and $\frac{2}{e}<1$.

Comment: I recently asked this question as well... and this answer doesn't at all seem to obviously work.  If I did something similar and the result failed on the order of 10^-11 for all n greater than 5.  This is to say, I feel your answer is too cavalier.... and if it can be made more rigorous would you please do this.  I spent several hours yesterday working on this, so it is not as if I haven't tried this approach or seriously considered it.  Can you clear it up more, please?

Comment: This answer could be completed if [this issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251647/) gets resolved

Answer (score 2):

Jack D'Aurizio's answer doesn't have any explicit bound for what $n$ is large enough to cut off the case work. Here's a possible way around this.

---

EDIT:
I managed to prove this by elementary means. Below is my old approach using properties of the $\Gamma$ function.

I'll start with the form $(n+1)((n+1)!)^{1/(n+1)}-n(n!)^{1/n}<n+1$.

Using AG, it's simple to see that $n!^{1/n}<(n+1)/2$, so we can deal with the following inequalities instead:
$$
(n+1)((n+1)!)^{1/(n+1)}-n(n!)^{1/n}<2(n!)^{1/n}\\ 
(n+1)((n+1)!)^{1/(n+1)}<(n+2)(n!)^{1/n}\\
(n+1)^{n+1}(n+1)n!<(n+2)^{n+1}n!(n!)^{1/n}\\
n+1<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}(n!)^{1/n}\\
n+1<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n!)^{1/n}
$$
In the last line I used the well-known inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. So now we have:
$$
\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}}\right)^n<n!
$$
We can use induction to get rid of $n!$. The inequality cleary holds for $n=2$. Then:
$$
(n+1)!=(n+1)n! >(n+1)\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}}\right)^n
$$
We could complete the induction step if we knew that
$$
(n+1)\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}}\right)^n\geq\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)^n}\right)^{n+1}\\
1\geq\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{n^n(n+2)^n}\right)^n\\
1\geq\frac{n+1}{n+2}\frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{n^n(n+2)^n}
$$
But rearranging a bit, we find:
$$
1\geq\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$
This is the well-known inequality from before, so we may now conclude our induction step:
$$
(n+1)!>(n+1)\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}}\right)^n\geq\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)^n}\right)^{n+1}
$$
And we are done.

---

OLD:
Define $f(x)=x(x!)^{1/x}$. The statement above amounts to proving $f(x+1)-f(x)<x+1$ for $x$ large enough and checking by hand for all smaller $n$. Now suppose we managed to show that beyond a certain $x$, we had $f'(x)<x$. Then by Lagrange's theorem there would be some $\xi\in(x,x+1)$ such that
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)<\xi<x+1
$$
To prove this, we'll have to make some pretty ugly bounds for $f'$. First:
$$
f'(x)=(x!)^{1/x}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\log(x!)+\psi(x+1)\right)
$$
Here $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Wikipedia has the following [estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for $x!$:
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}x^{x+1/2}e^{-x}\leq x!\leq e^{1-x}x^{x+1/2}
$$
Also, the digamma function page has the following [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Inequalities):
$$
\psi(x)<\log x-\frac{1}{2x}
$$
Putting all this together for $x>1$:
\begin{align}
f'(x)&<(e^{1-x}x^{x+1/2})^{1/x}\left(1+\log (x+1)-\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)+\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(x)-x\right)\right)\\
&<e^{1/x-1}x^{1+1/2x}(2+\log(x+1)-\log(x))\\
&<e^{1/x-1}x^{1+1/2x}(2+1/x)
\end{align}
Here I dropped a bunch of negative terms in the second line. I also used $\log(1+1/x)<1/x$ in the third line. Define $g(x)=e^{1/x-1}x^{1/2x}(2+1/x)$. Then we want to prove
$g(x)<1$. Apparently (I calculated this with Mathematica because I don't feel like differentiating $g$):
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-1+1/x}x^{-3+1/2x}(1+4x+(2x+1)\log(x))
$$
But this is negative for any $x>1$. Now we might numerically calculate that $g(9)\approx0.98$ and because $g$ is decreasing, we have $g<1$ for $x\geq 9$. Now all that remains is checking for all $n<9$.

I don't like this approach because it's too numerical at the end. At the same time, $f(x+1)-f(x)$ seems like a very well-behaved function - indeed, I'm sure there exists some way of going about this more analytically.

Comment: B E A U T I F U L... well actually rather ugly but an actually rigorous answer!
I wish that the digamma function and your g(x) were not involved however because the book that I pulled it from hasn't defined either of these...  it's from a chapter which covers the AGM inequality and Bernoulli inequality. The text is "More Calculus of a Single Variable".  

Well....  I think that for now... this is the best we have.  If I can derive a more clean proof I'll post it.....  until then, I believe your solution is the ONLY real solution (after one checks n=1,...9 which we leave to the reader LOL).

Comment: Some thoughts...  it might be helpful to split it up into cases.  If x(n) equals the product on the LHS, then a good strategy might be the following:
Suppose that for all $n\le N$ we have $x(n)<\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}$.  Then we could try proving the result by contradiction.  It may help to split it up into cases.  Case 1: Assume $x(N+1) = \frac{(N+1)!}{(N+2)^{N+1}}$ and derive a contradiction.  Case 2: Repeat with $=$ replaced by $>$.  Sometimes splitting this up helps.  unfortunately, it hasn't helped me yet.

Comment: @Squirtle Also, which book is the one you got this from?

Comment: More calculus of a single variable

Comment: Oh, that's the title, I thought it was the chapter...

Comment: @Squirtle I've added another derivation, I hope it's correct...