# How to prove this inequality involving factorials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factorial

$$(n+1)\cdot ((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} -n\cdot (n!)^\frac{1}{n}< n+1$$
Where n is a positive integer. One [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742118/an-inequality-with-exponents-factorials-and-nth-roots/1742172#1742172) said that this can be done using Stirling's approximation, but how? Is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: Induction can be tried.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Since $n!\approx \frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$ by Stirling's approximation, $n!^{1/n}$ roughly behaves like $\frac{n}{e}$, hence the LHS roughly is $\frac{2}{e}(n+1)<(n+1)$ and the inequality needs to be checked only for small values of $n$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you please clarify your argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251647)?

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3252345/631742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stirling approximation has a beauty within: it does work even for not so large $n$.

**Stirling Approximation**

Given $n!$, towards the Laplace methods for integrals, an approximation for the factorial reads:

$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Where $e$ is the Euler Number.

Clearly this does extend to

$$(n+a)! \approx \sqrt{2\pi (n+a)} \left(\frac{n+a}{e}\right)^{n+a}$$

In our case $a = 1$.

**The Inequality**

First thing first, let's clean it a bit, dividing by $n+1$:

$$[(n+1)!]^{1/(n+1)} - \frac{n}{n+1}(n!)^{1/n} < 1$$

Now we apply Stirling approximation, and being careful about the exponents we are lead eventually to

$$[2 \pi (n+1)]^{1/(2(n+1))}\frac{n+1}{e} - \frac{n^2}{e(n+1)}(2\pi n)^{1/2n} < 1$$

Now some consideration according to what $n$ is, are mandatory.

**Case 1: large $n$ values**

In this hypothesis there is nothing wrong if we say $n+1 \approx n$, hence we get

$$(2\pi n)^{1/2n}\frac{n}{e} - \frac{n}{e}(2\pi n)^{1/2n} < 1$$

$$0 < 1$$

Which holds, and it clearly always holds for large values of $n$.

**Case 2, small $n$ values**

In this case we may take a series expansion, by considering small values of $n$.

This is more a curiosity factorial as it's meant, is only defined for natural numbers, hence "small" values of $n$ would be $n = 1$.

Probably by induction you may also be able to prove the inequality, after the Stirling approximation, but for the sake of maths, here is the small $n$ values.

By a series expansion, taking only the very first terms, we have

$$[2 \pi (n+1)]^{1/(2(n+1))} \approx \sqrt{2\pi} + \frac{n\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(1 - \ln(2\pi))$$

and

$$(2\pi n)^{1/2n} \approx (2\pi)^{1/2n}\ e^{\ln(n)/2n}$$

Substituting it into the inequality will clearly show that the second term is always greater than the first one, because of the exponential term, hence if you condense the writing as

$$A - B < 1$$

this will always hold.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to make the argument for large $n$ more rigorous (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251647))?

Comment: Let's be clear.  In the linked post, the question asked wants a bound FOR ALL n.  This is not a solution except for sufficiently large N; and what is this N... who knows, it's not given.

Comment: @Squirtle Uhm I think I did not understand. I posted an answer both for large and small $N$, where have I missed something?

Comment: It just seems small N isn't well defined. Also approximations seem undesirable in something like this where after you play around with the problem long enough it seems true but you want a precise answer.... But approximations seem fuzzy. Maybe i don't fully appreciate how good the approximations are. However, i did this problem and using different but exact inequalities I failed to establish the desired inequality (it failed on the scale of 10^-11 in the wrong direction only for small n (n=2 or higher)... And the failure only got smaller for higher n s.t. it went to 0 as n to infinity)