# Tricky limit as $n$ tends to infinity of an expression involving a bunch of roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564744/how-to-prove-this-inequality-involving-factorials), @user513057 asked how to prove that for $n$ large enough,
$$
(n+1)\cdot ((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} -n\cdot (n!)^\frac{1}{n}< n+1
$$

In the answer by @Von Neumann, the latter rewrote this inequality as 
$$
[2 \pi (n+1)]^{1/(2(n+1))}\frac{n+1}{e} - \frac{n^2}{e(n+1)}(2\pi n)^{\frac1{2n}} < 1
$$

Then he argued, that one can replace $n+1$ by $n$ if $n$ is large enough. I don't see how to formally justify this though.

In order to do this, I would like to determine the limit

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} [2 \pi (x+1)]^{1/(2(x+1))}\frac{x+1}{e} - \frac{x^2}{e(x+1)}(2\pi x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}.
$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit((2*Pi*(n%2B1))%5E(1%2F(2*n%2B2))*(n%2B1)%2Fexp(1)-n%5E2*(2*Pi*n)%5E(1%2F(2*n))%2F((exp(1))(n%2B1)),n%3Dinfinity)) says that this limit equals $\frac2e$. I don't see any way of proving this though.

I tried computing the derivative of the above function in order to show that it is decreasing, but that didn't lead to any results. I also tried computing the difference of the $n+1$-st and the $n$-th term, but that didn't work either.

> EDIT: This is equivalent to proving that
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x\left((x+1)\cdot\frac{x+1}e\cdot \sqrt[2(x+1)]{2\pi(x+1)}-x\cdot\frac{x}e\cdot \sqrt[2x]{2\pi x}\right)=\frac2e
> $$
>   or equivalently that
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x\left((x+1)^2\cdot \sqrt[2(x+1)]{2\pi(x+1)}-x^2\cdot \sqrt[2x]{2\pi x}\right)=2
> $$
>   or rewritten again that 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^2}x\cdot \sqrt[2(x+1)]{2\pi(x+1)}-x\cdot \sqrt[2x]{2\pi x}=2
> $$

[Wolfram Alpha query for the last limit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit(1%2F(x)*((x%2B1)%5E2*(2+pi+(x%2B1))%5E(1%2F(2(x%2B1)))-x%5E2*(2+pi+x)%5E(1%2F(2x))),x%3Dinfinity)).

> EDIT 2:
>   Using l'Hospital, one could also prove that 
>   \begin{multline}
> \frac12 (4x-\ln(2\pi (x+1))+5) (2\pi (x+1))^{1/(2 x+2)}\\-2 (2\pi x)^{1/(2x)}(x-(1/4)\ln(2\pi x)+\frac14)
> \end{multline}
>   converges to $2$.

[Third Wolfram Alpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit((1%2F2)*(4*x-ln(2*Pi*(x%2B1))%2B5)*(2*Pi*(x%2B1))%5E(1%2F(2*x%2B2))-2*(2*Pi*x)%5E(1%2F(2*x))*(x-(1%2F4)*ln(2*Pi*x)%2B1%2F4),x%3Dinfinity))

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250902/how-to-calculate-limit-as-n-tends-to-infinity-of-fracn1n2n1n-n)

Comment: This really does NOT address the original question, however.  That is, show that $(\sqrt2-1)\cdots(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!}) < \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}$ for all $n$.   The answer on this page merely proves that the result follows for sufficiently large n.  What is that n, however?  We must know, because to then "close the proof" one must directly demonstrate the inequality also holds for all m<n (presumably manually checking each).  If n is one billion then such a check is neither practical nor atheistically pleasing.  I say the question is STILL open.

Comment: To be clear....  I was already aware of these limit arguments (I derived some of my own), however they don't show us rigorously what "for large n" means.

Comment: @Squirtle I understand your concerns. I tried playing around with the inequality you're interested in and got stuck. While this technically isn't the main goal of this question, perhaps it should be made into its own question, I certainly find it interesting!

Comment: It was....  and the 'police' closed my question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250980/show-that-sqrt2-1-cdots-sqrtn1n1-sqrtnn-fracnn1)  calling it a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742118/an-inequality-with-exponents-factorials-and-nth-roots.... 

However it is not a duplicate....  because I have put emphasis that the other question and answer never really addressed my concern .... I'm glad at least one person is carefully reading the question!

Comment: @Squirte I may be onto something (not sure) but it's too long for a comment, is there some kind of "Latex" chat room or something here?

Comment: @Squirtle I've added another answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742118/an-inequality-with-exponents-factorials-and-nth-roots/3252345#3252345

Comment: I believe there is ....  I've never used it though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using the form
$$
L=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{x}\left(2\pi(x+1)\right)^{\frac{1}{2(x+1)}}-x\left(2\pi x\right)^{\frac{1}{2x}}\right).
$$
We'll look at the function
$$
f(x)=(2\pi x)^{1/2x}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2x}\log(2\pi x)\right).
$$
First note that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$, so we can simplify the original limit:

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\frac{(x+1)^2f(x+1)-x^2f(x)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\color{orange}{\frac{x^2f(x+1)-x^2f(x)}x}
+\color{blue}{\frac{2xf(x+1)}x}
+\color{green}{\frac{f(x+1)}{x}}\\
&=\color{blue}2+\color{green}0+\color{orange}{\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}x(f(x+1)-f(x))}\\
&=2+\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}x(f(x+1)-f(x)).
\end{align}
Now use Lagrange's theorem to write $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi(x))$ for some $\xi\in(x,x+1)$. To make use of this, we evaluate the limit of $g(x)=xf'(x)$:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}xf'(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}f(x)\frac{1-\log(2\pi x)}{2x}=0
$$
Since $\xi(x)\in(x,x+1)$ we have:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}x(f(x+1)-f(x))=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\xi(x)f'(\xi(x))+(x-\xi(x))f'(\xi(x))=\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}g(\xi(x))=0
$$
Recall that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\xi(x)=\infty$; the term with $x-\xi(x)$ disappears as this expression is bounded and $f'(\xi(x))$ vanishes in the limit. The very last equality holds because of $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\xi(x)=\infty$. This establishes $L=2$.

---

EDIT: Here's an approach without Lagrange's theorem. We'll again look at the limit
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}x(f(x+1)-f(x))
$$
Calculating $f''$, we find
$$
f''(x)=f(x)\left(\left(\frac{1-\log{2\pi x}}{2x^2}\right)^2+\frac{2\log{2\pi x}-3}{2x^3}\right)
$$
In particular, for large $x:f''(x)>0$. This means the function is convex and because $f'<0$ for large $x$, we can estimate
$$
\vert f(x+1)-f(x)\vert < |f'(x)|\cdot 1=\vert f'(x)\vert
$$
But since $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}xf'(x)=0$, this implies $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}x(f(x+1)-f(x))=0$.

Comment: Very nice answer! I allowed myself to edit out the $O$ and to add in some colors, because the former wasn't needed and the latter makes this answer even more readable in my opinion. Tell me if that is fine for you :)

Comment: Sure, thanks! When I was fiddling around with this at first, I wasn't very efficient and the $O$'s popped up, so I agree removing them makes the step clearer.